# THttpRio https (Wininet) with ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED error message

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl, delphi-xe7

I am using Delphi XE7, win 8.1 in a PC with no installed certificate.

I have  the next Web service https://wsp.hom.orizonbrasil.com.br:6214/tiss/v30200/tissSolicitacaoProcedimento

When I invoke a web service I get this exception in Delphi XE7:
"A certificate is required to complete client authentication - URL:https://wsp.hom.orizonbrasil.com.br:6214/tiss/v30200/tissSolicitacaoProcedimento - SOAPAction:""

The connection is not blocked by port as I tried with SOAPUI (java) and got the response from this web service.

I am trying to use Altova xml spy and I get an error similar to delphi XE7.

Why SoapUI works while  XE7 and XML SPY have certificate problem?

Comment: The webservice is using certificate-based authentication, you will need to install/supply a certificate that the webservice trusts.

Comment: Please check [here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.webservices/two-way-ssl/1078522) for more clues.

Comment: Although I have not installed certificate, SoapUI works great. When I send a request with SoapUI I have an answer and it does not complain of lack of certificate. So, why HTTPRio(Delphi) and XML SPY have problems with the webservice with a message requiring a certificate? Luiz

Comment: In SoapUI, go to the Preferences page, SSL Settings tab, and verify that you do not have a cert attached.  SoapUI can attach a cert from a .pfx or .cer file, and that certificate does NOT have to be installed on the machine.  This would be the easy answer.

Comment: I have checked Preference page in SoapUI and I have no installed certifcate. As I said, it works great. I post a request and I receive a correct response. With Delphi XE7 and XMLSPY I have a response saying a certificate is required to complete client authentication.

Comment: Hi, the site where is hosted the webservice https://wsp.hom.orizonbrasil.com.br:6214/tiss/v30200/tissSolicitacaoProcedimento  accepts certificate but it´s not needed. I have tested with http indy with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL  and I access the site to download wsdl without certificate problems. Indy doesn´t ask for certficate. The problem is with WinInet. XE7 SOAP using wininet is not able to works in this case. So, How to use wiininet to access a https site that accepts certificate  but it´s not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the certificate is in the ROOT certificate store (trusted root certificates) for the local system.

THTTPRIO will not load those by default in Delphi (therefore, it can't find the correct one to use), instead, it looks in the MY certificate store for the current USER.  To force the component to use the ROOT certificate store, you have to provide an OnBeforePost so it can open the correct store where the certificate is actually present.

```
procedure Form1.OnBeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);

const
  CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM_A   = LPCSTR(9);
  CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM_W   = LPCSTR(10);
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM     = CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM_W;
  {$ELSE}
  CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM     = CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM_A;
  {$ENDIF}


  CERT_STORE_NO_CRYPT_RELEASE_FLAG            = $00000001;
  CERT_STORE_SET_LOCALIZED_NAME_FLAG          = $00000002;
  CERT_STORE_DEFER_CLOSE_UNTIL_LAST_FREE_FLAG = $00000004;
  CERT_STORE_DELETE_FLAG                      = $00000010;
  CERT_STORE_MANIFOLD_FLAG                    = $00000100;
  CERT_STORE_ENUM_ARCHIVED_FLAG               = $00000200;
  CERT_STORE_UPDATE_KEYID_FLAG                = $00000400;
  CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG                    = $00008000;
  CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG               = $00004000;
  CERT_STORE_CREATE_NEW_FLAG                  = $00002000;
  CERT_STORE_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_FLAG             = $00001000;

  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER_ID  = 1;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE_ID = 2;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION_SHIFT   = 16;

  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_SERVICE_ID  = 4;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES_ID         = 5;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_USERS_ID            = 6;

  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER    = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER_ID shl CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION_SHIFT;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE   = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE_ID shl CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION_SHIFT;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_SERVICE = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_SERVICE_ID shl CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION_SHIFT;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES        = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES_ID shl CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION_SHIFT;
  CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_USERS           = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_USERS_ID shl CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION_SHIFT;

  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  CERT_STORE:PWChar = 'Root';
  {$ELSE}
  CERT_STORE:PAnsiChar = 'Root';
  {$ENDIF}

var
  HTTPRStore: IClientCertInfo;
  hStore: pointer;
  Flags: cardinal;

begin
  HTTPReqResp.InvokeOptions:=[soPickFirstClientCertificate,soIgnoreInvalidCerts];

  if UseSystemCertStore
    then
      begin
        Flags:=CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG or CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG or CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE or CERT_STORE_DEFER_CLOSE_UNTIL_LAST_FREE_FLAG;
        HTTPRStore:=HTTPReqResp as IClientCertInfo;
        try
          hStore:=CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
            0,
            0,
            Flags,
            CERT_STORE);
          HTTPRStore.SetCertStore(hStore);
        finally
          HTTPRStore:=nil;
        end;
      end;
end;
```